# XCTest UI testing UIElements size

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, ui-testing, xcode-ui-testing

I am testing my app with XCTest in XCode.

Does someone has example how to test UIElement size?
Height of cell in tableView, or height of label in tableView cell. Any example will be appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the [`XCUIElementAttributes`](http://masilotti.com/xctest-documentation/Protocols/XCUIElementAttributes.html) protocol on `XCUIElement` to access the frame. This returns a standard `CGRect` which you can query for size and origin.

```
let height = app.buttons.element.frame.size.height
let width = app.buttons.element.frame.size.width
let x = app.buttons.element.frame.origin.x
let y = app.buttons.element.frame.origin.y
```

Comment: @DejanZuza you're welcome! If this sufficiently answers your question please accept it by clicking the gray checkmark to the left. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Joe, could i ask you to look this problem of mine. Thanks
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33872364/uitesting-xctest-current-viewcontroller-class

Comment: @JoeMasilotti Still helps in 2017!